# OSMdroid keeps navigating back to setcenter position, why?

Tags: android, android-mapview, openstreetmap, osmdroid

---

Dear Folks, I have an osmdroid map version 4.2, and slf version 1.5.8

I also have this java code set for it (down there).
My issue is, where ever I set the "setCenter" method, and launch the map, then i try to navigate,the system right away shifts me a back towards the defualt coordinates that i have set previously.

any idea how to allow me to freely navigate with predefined centers?

```
 package com.example.com.example;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;

public class OSM_Map extends Activity {

    private MapView mapView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_osm__map);

        mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);


        //IMapController mapController  = mapView.getController();
        mapView.getController().setZoom(11);



        ViewTreeObserver vto = mapView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {      //VERY IMPORTANT, DRAWS LAYOUT FIRST, then positions
                mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(40.712784,-74.005941));
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onGlobalLayout listener is being called repeatly and resets the center to your predefined point afterwards.

You need to remove the listener by adding the following after you set the center initially:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) 
            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        else
            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
```

Comment: I did insert this code right after setCenter inside the globalLayout, however, it shot and error out, saying "call requires api level 16... " on the 2nd line from your code. However, I just added  mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);  and it perfectly works!

Comment: Yes, the function changed from removeGlobalOnLayoutListener() to removeOnGlobalLayoutListener() since API 16, which is why the conditional statement is here (Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN is 16).  But if your target sdk is below 16, then just call removeGlobalOnLayoutListener().